# How to deep link my android app to paytm and freecharge app?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am creating an android application for browsing plans and tariff of mobile recharges. What I want is that when the user selects a plan from my app, then on clicking either of the one option ie paytm or freecharge:

> 1. The mobile recharge screen of the respective app gets open.
> 2. User's phone number and amount of recharge gets prefilled.

As far as I know this is possible either through Intends or Deeplinking. But the problem is that:

> 1. If I use intends and open paytm/freecharge using their package names it will open the home screen of those apps. Now how to open the
>      recharge mobile screen and prefill the numbers and recharge amount??
> 2. If I follow the deeplink approach, for either of the apps what url to call and what parameters to pass?? I got a deeplink url of paytm in
>      their [api docs](https://paytm.com/blog/deep-link-your-apps-to-drive-engagement/) but that too opens only the home screen.

Once this is done, user can proceed to recharge via both these apps. I have seen this feature in a similar app [ireff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.ireff.android&hl=en) and thats excatly what I want to implement.

[image: Mobile recharge screen of freecharge app]
[image: Mobile recharge screen of paytm app]

Above are the screen on which I want to reach and fill in the phone number and amount which user has filled on my app. Please let me know how to do this I couldn't find anything useful about this on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to do this then?

Comment: No I wasn't. We skipped the freecharge funtionality for now.

Comment: Hello Ashwani, for PayTM were you able to do this? Can you tell me high level steps.

Comment: @vkb you can refer to this link https://blog.paytm.com/deep-link-your-apps-to-drive-engagement-ff17f1d2ed0d

Comment: thanks sir @AshwaniKumar for the link...... what would be the url for loading payement page? with particular number inside it

Comment: @josekj Extremely sorry but I don't have that code now. I did it 2yrs back so can't recal.

Comment: ok.... anyway thanks for quick replay

Answer (score 1):

I have done for paytm in kotlin

```
fun paytm(amount:String,contact_number:String){
val intent = Intent()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(PaytmConstants.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, amount)
bundle.putString(
PaytmConstants.PAYEE_MOBILE_NUMBER,
contact_number
)
bundle.putBoolean(PaytmConstants.IS_MOBILE_NUMBER_EDITABLE, false)
bundle.putBoolean(PaytmConstants.IS_AMOUNT_EDITABLE, false)
intent.component = ComponentName("net.one97.paytm", "net.one97.paytm.AJRJarvisSplash")
intent.putExtra(PaytmConstants.PAYMENT_MODE, 1)
intent.putExtra(PaytmConstants.MERCHANT_DATA, bundle)
startActivityForResult(intent, 103)
}
```

Comment: also brother if possible replace PaytmConstants with correct string value